# Mysql slow concurrent GROUP BY queries

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have weird problem with mysql and GROUP BY queries. See below:

```
mysqlslap --concurrency=5 --iterations=1 --query=/root/test.sql --create-     schema=testd  -u root -p
Benchmark
        Average number of seconds to run all queries: 2.575 seconds
        Minimum number of seconds to run all queries: 2.575 seconds
        Maximum number of seconds to run all queries: 2.575 seconds
        Number of clients running queries: 5
        Average number of queries per client: 1
```

But when I'm running just 1 query it will look like this:

```
mysqlslap --concurrency=1 --iterations=1 --query=/root/test.sql --create-    schema=testd  -u root -p
Benchmark
        Average number of seconds to run all queries: 0.247 seconds
        Minimum number of seconds to run all queries: 0.247 seconds
        Maximum number of seconds to run all queries: 0.247 seconds
        Number of clients running queries: 1
        Average number of queries per client: 1
```

test.sql file includes just this one query:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `name` FROM logs GROUP BY `name`;
```

When I remove GROUP BY it executes just fine and doesn't slow down like before.

Mysql version is 5.5.43. CPU is E5-1660v3 and there is 32GB RAM available. my.cnf file is default except these values:

```
key_buffer              = 256M
key_buffer_size         = 256M
sort_buffer_size    = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 1M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
max_allowed_packet      = 32M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover          = BACKUP
max_connections     = 300
table_cache     = 256M
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
```

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Dumb question but you have name field indexed in table logs?

Comment: Yes, I tried indexing it but it didn't do anything.

Comment: how many records do you have in your `logs` table? what is table size? show us your `CREATE TABLE` statement for `logs` please